# Change controls in Datagridview after data bind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm not even sure if this is possible, but let's say that I take a Datatable and bind it to my DataGridView. Would it be possible to set column 3 to be a dropdownlist instead of displaying some text? 
EDIT: Similar issue, my code is only grabbing the first checked checkbox and ignoring all others?

```
  //Should iterate over every row      
  for(int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
//Grab the checkbox in the row
            CheckBox chkDelete = (CheckBox) GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("opCheck");
            if(chkDelete != null)
            {
//If the checkbox exists, see if it is checked
                if(chkDelete.Checked)
                {
 //If it is checked, write out the SQL command and delete it from the database
                    //Write out the SQL command to delete whatever is checked
                    command = "SQL_STATEMENT";


                    cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, con);
                    //Execute the command and fill the data set
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    BindData();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
            }

        }
            con.Dispose();
            con.Close();
```

Comment: You might try throwing this up on sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You have more control over each column if you use `ItemTemplate` for each column. Then you set a `OnDataBinding` parm to the method that populates that column for each row. Using templates allows you to define almost any ASP or HTML element for a given column.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks~
But now I'm having a similar issue with checkboxes. I need to iterate over every row in my GridView and check to see if a checkbox is checked. But, it's only grabbing the first checked checkbox if I have multiple checkboxes checked. Please look at my edited post